# Does the word “too” in a series of items decide the placement of the conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

Original:

> A boy, a girl and a dog too went for a walk.

Would the original or the following be better, or does it change the meaning?

> A boy and a girl, and a dog too went for a walk.

Is there any improvement with regards to commas that you can suggest?

Comment: Drop the "too": "A boy, a girl, and a dog went for a walk". If you want to really underscore that the dog joined he boy and the girl, break it out into a separate clause or sentence "A boy and a girl went for a walk. A dog came along too."

Comment: @Dan Bron Dropping the 'too' removes a required emphasis on the dog, so it in effect changes the meaning. And in my view it is quite unnecessary to add a further sentence. Whilst the OPs example does call for parenthetical commas, I think it only needs one 'and'. *A boy, a girl, and a dog too, went for a walk* does the job perfectly.

Comment: There's nothing grammatically wrong with using two 'and's, although in terms of style I like the original better. And it should be punctuated *"A boy and a girl, and a dog too, went for a walk"*.

Comment: I guess I'm questioning if the emphasis on the dog is, in fact, required. If I saw it written in a story *for* children, I know it's intentional (-ly cutesy). If I saw it in a story *by* a child, I'd want him/her to first understand that in typical written and spoken English, there would be no "too",and to add it must be a conscious, explicit choice, designed to produce a specific effect (and I'd want the child to understand what that effect is, to a great enough extent to explain it to me).

Comment: @Dan: what is wrong with that ***too***? You don't need it, but if you want to emphasize the dog, you can use it. And children don't need telling that; they understand it naturally. I can't imagine a child thinking they have to say *"a thing and another thing and a third thing too"* to list three things.

Comment: @Peter, see my comment directly above yours (and see the word "underscore" in the original comment, so you know I didn't miss the sense of emphasis).

Comment: @WS2 But if *and a dog too* is wrapped by parenthetical commas, then it doesn’t fulfil the rule of the sentence making sense without the parenthetical phrase, or does it?

`A boy, a girl went for a walk.`

Comment: @LWTBP Good spot, but whether or not items in a 'list' should be considered 'parenthetical' depends on terminology, and probably on what is intended by the speaker / writer. Note the difference between the unmarked "A boy, a girl, and a dog went for a walk." and "A boy, a girl – and a dog – went for a walk." (where the dog's presence is either emphasised or added as an afterthought). "A boy, a girl, and a dog too, went for a walk." and "A boy and a girl, and a dog too, went for a walk." are grammatical, no matter how one chooses to classify the structures.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence the 'too' doesn't seem to add to or change the meaning.

In the second, using "a boy and a girl" works to suggest they are a pair, in that traditional romantic sense, which the first sentence doesn't, since there they are separately listed.

The 'too' in the second case seems to help that reading. "a boy and a girl, and a dog too" seems to reinforce the separateness of the "a dog" item from the "a boy and a girl" item. Whereas if you'd just put "a boy and a girl, and a dog", one might tend to read it as a wordy kind of list - "a boy and a girl and a dog".

But this kind of nuance may be a little subjective.

Comment: Damn, I should have thought up a better pair of words than *boy* and *girl*! I don't want to make them out to be a pair. All three words in the list are supposed to be having the same weight.